# jQuery .animate fade going nuts

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout

Complete noob to jQuery here. Its syntax is very different from other languages so I am having a bit of a hard time with it. I managed to get it to do the small part I needed it to, which is changing the background color of the page on hover.

However, the buttons that I am hovering over are very close to each other and if you quickly move from one button to another the fade animations will pile up and continue to change the background color even after you stop moving the mouse over the buttons.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index.html</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bgcolor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class='splash'>

    <div id='logoblock'>
        <img src='images/logo.png'>
    </div>

    <div id='menublock'>
        <a href='#' id='jabout'><div id='about'></div></a>
        <a href='#' id='jphoto'><div id='photo'></div></a>
        <a href='#' id='jinfo' ><div id='info'></div></a>
    </div>

    <div id='quoteblock'
        <p class=quote>"blah blah blah!"</p>
        <p class=author>- John Doe</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

bgcolor.js

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#jphoto" ).hover(
    function() {
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: '#bde2ff',}, 100);
    },
    function() {
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: '#d4e88f',});
    }   
);

$( "#jabout" ).hover(
    function() {
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: '#f5ff53',}, 100);
    },
    function() {
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: '#d4e88f',});
    }
);

$( "#jinfo" ).hover(
    function() {
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: '#fff4ff',}, 100);
    },
    function() {
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: '#d4e88f',});
    }   
);

});
```

I have also tried changing the OUT effect of the .hover() function to

```
$('body').css('background', '#d4e88f');
```

But that still did not solve my problem.

How can I make that little glitch go away if someone moves between buttons too quick?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: jQuery isn’t a programming language.

Comment: I guess it really depends what your goal is.  How exactly do you want these animations to act?  There were a few options stated below about using a variable to control if an animation can fire or do you want to stop the current animation to start a new one?  How do you envision the code reacting to the user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using `$('body').stop().animate` instead of `$('body').animate`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it in the past:

```
var Animating = false; // Set a variable
```

Before the Animation:

```
if (!Animating) { // If not animating
Animating = true; // Set true
```

On complete:

```
Animating = false; // Set false
```